# Writing shell script to scan a list of folders

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file `folders.txt`

```
one
two
three
four
...
```

that has a list of folder names. [`one`, `two`, `three` and `four` are names of folders].

Each of these folders has a number of files of different types (different extensions). I want a list of all the files in all the folders of one particular extension, say `.txt`.

***How should my shell script look like?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the post is simply asking for a list of files, it's quite simple:

```
tmp=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") 
for i in `cat folders.txt` ; do
    ls -l "$i/*.txt"
done
IFS=$tmp
```

Comment: take care of folder names with spaces. put quotes where necessary

Comment: even though the original post is not asking for it, I've added it.  note, your examples are not all taking spaces into consideration.

Comment: so which one is not correct wrt files with spaces? you have not told me, so i can correct it.

Comment: i did tell you --> your usage of 'read' is problematic. you use it in 3 places.  "man read" is your friend.

Comment: I know, it doesn't take care of things like newlines in files. But for spaces, its more than fine. Why don't you try them out and see. If it doesn't work for you, let me know which version and I will try and correct them.

Comment: it's your example, spend some time with it and you'll see what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

one way

```
while read -r folders
do
  # add -maxdepth 1 if recursive traversal is not required
  find "$folders" -type f -iname "*.txt" | while read -r FILE
  do
      echo "do something with $FILE"
  done
done <"file"
```

or

```
folders=$(<file)
find $folders -type f -iname "*.txt" | while read -r FILE
do
    echo "do something with $FILE"
done
```

Bash 4.0 (if recursive find is required)

```
shopt -s globstar
folders=$(<file)
for d in $folders
do
  for file in $d/**/*.txt
  do
    echo "do something with $file"
  done
done
```

Comment: I would add the -prune option to find so that subdirs aren't searched

Comment: OP doesn't indicate, but he can always add `-maxdepth 1` if he doesn't want to traverse directory

Answer (score 2):

Simply do it on command line:

```
xargs ls -l < folders.txt | grep '.txt$'
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer.

Comment: lose the cat and its even simpler. `xargs ls -l < folder.txt`. or `xargs -a folder.txt ls -l`

Comment: @Ethan, i like the simplicity too, but only for displaying those txt files. If further processing for each file is required, this has to be enhanced.